# POST data with Curl on a specific port with HTTPS

Tags: php, curl

I try to send data to my application with a POST.
The url is a bit tricky, it' s https only and on a specific port

Here is my code

```
$url = 'https://mysite.com/foo.php';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

if ($type == "POST") {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
}

if ($environment == 'test') {
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 1234);
}


$result = curl_exec($curl);

if (curl_errno($curl) > 0) {
   $result = 'Internal server error, error: ' . curl_errno($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);
```

It returns a error 7 `Failed to connect() to host`.

What did i made wrong?

**UPDATE** :

After bodi0 advices i add

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

**UPDATE2** :

It was a network issue, my code was ok...

Comment: You are using something like `$url = 'https://mysite.com/foo.php';` instead of the erroneous `$url = https://mysite.com.foo.php` right?

Comment: Yes i do the `url` is a string, generated in another controller actually

Comment: Oh ok, I had to ask just in case =)

Comment: Could you check if this works with something like `$url = 'https://google.com';` on the standard port?
Just to make sure the problem is specific to your URL and does not involve any firewall rules or other client side restrictions. And can you open your URL on the specific port directly in your browser? Make sure your server is configured to accept requests on that port.

Comment: Yeah i can  open the url in my browser, and if i `curl -P 1234 https://mysite.com/foo.php` it just works

Comment: Maybe you could compare the command-line request and the PHP request and see what's different. Have a look at `CURLOPT_FILE` and `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` (http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). On command line it should be something like `curl -P 1234 --verbose --trace https://mysite.com/foo.php`. Maybe there are essential differences in the headers that make the request from PHP fail, like a missing user agent or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to setting the port number like this:

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 8088);` where 8088 is your real port number.

Also the proper way of handling the SSL requests involves setting the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` parameter:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/folder/your-secure-certificate.crt");
```

This ensures **that not just any server certificate will be trusted** by your `cURL` session.

For example, if an attacker were to **somehow redirect traffic** from `api.example.com` to their own server, the `cURL` session **here would not properly initialize**, since the attacker would **not have access to a server certificate** (i.e. would not have the private key) trusted by the CA we added.

**EDIT:**

Many hosting companies don't allow connections "back" to your own host from your own PHP programs so perhaps that's what's happening here. Also try to apply the proxy settings, which is used in your LAN and see if it works, add this to your code if necessary:

`$proxy = '127.0.0.1:8888';`

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);`

Comment: Hum, i tried to remove the `'` between the port number, it still returns error 7...

Comment: Move the `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 8088);` at top, outside the `if ($environment == 'test')` condition and see what happens.

Comment: I tested it, the script goes into that condition.

Comment: Try adding the `curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Comment: I got no `location` in the `foo.php` where i send data to. Can i pass the port in the url like `mysite.com:1234` and remove the `CURLOPT_PORT` function?

Comment: No, port number must be specified as in example code. Try adding `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);` also, with your code.

Comment: I put the verifyhost & the followlocation function. Same error 7

Comment: This is weird, do you use any type of PROXY or your URL is at SUB-DOMAIN?

Comment: Yep, the server is behind a huge firewall and this is a subdomain too, but as i mentionned above, i can `curl` with command line